# CGAL Qt linker error

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, linker, cgal

I have a problem with compile project with CGAL and Qt in VisualStudio 2013. I try demo app of Polyhedron in CGAL demos and after I try to move *Scene* to my own Qt project.

Errors are like:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const CGAL::Three::Viewer_interface::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@Viewer_interface@Three@CGAL@@2UQMetaObject@@B) ...\Scene_polyhedron_item.obj
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class QColor const CGAL::Three::Scene_item::defaultColor" (?defaultColor@Scene_item@Three@CGAL@@2VQColor@@B)    ...\Scene_polyhedron_item.obj

- Qt: 5.5
- CGAL: 4.8.beta-1
- VisualStudio: 2013 x64

Linker input :

- C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\lib\Qt5Core.lib
- C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\lib\Qt5Gui.lib
- C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\lib\Qt5OpenGL.lib
- C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\lib\Qt5OpenGLExtensions.lib
- C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\lib\Qt5Widgets.lib
- C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\lib\Qt5Svg.lib
- C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\lib\Qt5Xml.lib
- CGAL_Qt5-vc120-mt-4.8.lib
- C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\lib\qtmain.lib

moc_* files are generated every build

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: did you link you libCGALQt5?

Comment: @sloriot What do you mean ? I have only one lib from cgal for Qt What i found - CGAL_Qt5-vc120-mt-4.8.lib ..

Comment: Yeah that one. did you link with it?

Comment: @sloriot Yes, i have it in linker -> input

Comment: Do you have the lib demo_framework compiled? If yes you must link with it.

Comment: Yes demo_framework.lib it is in linker->input

Comment: Without seeing the full project I have no further idea, sorry.

Comment: Or do you know something like skeleton (minimal) gui app for display 3d model with CGAL and Qt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in preprocesor constant of lib ... where was set to EXPORT, but have to be IMPORT.

So Now it is working, jus